# Cocoapods generates invalid umbrella header

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using MDCSwipeToChooseView from the following repository:

https://github.com/clsource/MDCSwipeToChoose

and Cocoapods generates an umbrella header which looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MDCSwipeToChoose.h"
#import "MDCSwipeOptions.h"
#import "MDCSwipeOptions.m"
#import "MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions.h"
#import "MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions.m"
#import "MDCPanState.h"
#import "MDCPanState.m"
#import "MDCSwipeDirection.h"
#import "MDCSwipeResult.h"
#import "MDCSwipeResult.m"
#import "MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate.h"
#import "MDCSwipeToChooseView.h"
#import "MDCSwipeToChooseView.m"
#import "UIView+MDCSwipeToChoose.h"
#import "UIView+MDCSwipeToChoose.m"

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MDCSwipeToChooseVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MDCSwipeToChooseVersionString[];
```

which is wrong because the compiler says the following:

[image: compiler error]

If I remove all the `.m` imports manually, I can compile the code but every time I run `pod install` or `pod update` again, it regenerates the wrong header.
I am using Swift and I have enabled `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile.

Is something wrong with the Cocoapod? How could I fix this?

Comment: Try to add `:submodules => true` in the pods: `pod "MDCSwipeToChoose", :submodules => true`. Not sure though, Could be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the MDCSwipeToChoose.podspec is incorrect. It lists public headers with both .h and .m files:

```
s.public_header_files = 'MDCSwipeToChoose/Public/**/*.{h,m}'
```

I'm guessing it should just be:

```
s.public_header_files = 'MDCSwipeToChoose/Public/**/*.h'
```

Ask the author to fix this. Or fork it and fix your copy.